# Crear App IOS responsive con Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Hola soy bastante nuevo en esto, como indica el titulo necesito hacer que mi aplicación se pueda adaptar a todos los dispositivos, he tratado muchas formas pero cuando genero los constraints para un tipo de dispositivo se rompe la interfaz para otro dispositivo, por ejemplo si lo dejo la view perfectamente para un iphone 4, si lo quiero ver en un iphones 8 los elementos cambian de lugar y tamaño...
desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Deberías ser más concreto con tu pregunta. Estás creando la vista con la interfaz gráfica o mediante código?

El tamaño de la pantalla de iphone 4 no es igual que un iPhone 8 por eso se te descolocan los elementos.

Lo mas fácil es usar las constraints de autolayout con la interfaz gráfica: selecciona el objeto que quieras y establece las restricciones que desees,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo fija la distancia de un elemento a los bordes de la pantalla y su tamaño  se adaptará según las medidas del teléfono

Comment: Hola Leemur!, muchas gracias por tu respuesta...
Tienes razón no formule bien mi pregunta, lo estoy haciendo con la interfaz gráfica utilizando AL, lo que me comentas es lo qu he estado haciendo, antes de formular mi pregunta ya habia investigado sobre el tema, pero no entiendo porque cuando agrego los constrains (por cierto agrego los que AL me sugiere), al cambiar a otro tamaño de pantalla, mi view se deforma completamente..., de todas formas agradezco de verdad tu respuesta,
por ultimo agregar mis disculpas por responder 2 dias tardes...

Comment: No hay problema, es difícil se concreto a veces. Si muestras una captura de pantalla de tu storyboard tal vez pueda decirte si veo alguna cosa extraña